# After format window partition size reduced to 30 gb

Tags: windows-10, disk-space, reinstall, partition-recovery

This morning I saw my window was stuck at boot page with system date and time it was not coming out then I decided to format this window 10. During format I saw laptop volume was only showing 30 gb I thought once I format and install window I would see rest 470 gb in unallocated volume but it is not there when I check in command prompt list disk it is only showing c drive size which is 30 gb. Please help

Comment: You should be able to extend your system partition in Windows 10 by opening the disk management of Window, select the system partition and select extend in it's context menu.

Answer (score 0):

As Robert said, you can extend that partition, but only if it's the last one on the disk if you are using Disk Management in Windows. There are other tools available that will let you do this.

Your other option is to reinstall Windows but this time, delete all of the partitions when you have the chance and then either let Windows build them automatically or build them yourself. The first option might be the best for you.